# Replacing all the cells with 0 except few specified values R

Tags: r

I have a data frame(df) which looks like,

```
  Id     Name       Activity.
  1      ABC        a;sldkj kkkdk
  2      two         llsjdfljs
  3      three       case one
  4      four        randshsjl lskjd
  5      five        case seven
  8      eight        sllslsll.asdhf
  9      nine         case ten
```

I want the replace all values in Activity to '0' except 'case one', 'case seven', 'case ten'

```
  Id     Name       Activity.
  1      ABC        0
  2      two        0
  3      three      case one
  4      four       0
  5      five       case seven
  8      eight      0
  9      nine       case ten
```

I tried,

```
    df2 <- subset(df, df$`Activity.!='case one'|df$`Activity.`!='case two'|df$`Activity.`!='case three')
    df2$Activity <- 0
    df <- merge(df,df2)
```

which becomes lengthy in code, so I was looking for some better solution

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @akrun it was a multiple press, wrong dial, added it again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
df1$"Activity."[!grepl('^case', df1$"Activity.")] <- 0
df1
#   Id  Name  Activity.
#1  1   ABC          0
#2  2   two          0
#3  3 three   case one
#4  4  four          0
#5  5  five case seven
#6  8 eight          0
#7  9  nine   case ten
```

If there are more `case` and we want to only `grep` on the above mentioned 'case'

```
df1$"Activity."[grepl('^case\\s+(one|seven|ten)', df1$"Activity.")] <- 0
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, a faster and efficient method would be to `set` 'Activity.' as the 'key' column after converting to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1,..`), and then assign (`:=`), the values in 'Activity' to '0' that are not 'case one', or 'case seven', ...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key='Activity.')[!(paste('case', c('one', 'seven', 
                    'ten'))), Activity. := '0']
df1
#   Id  Name  Activity.
#1:  1   ABC          0
#2:  3 three   case one
#3:  5  five case seven
#4:  9  nine   case ten
#5:  2   two          0
#6:  4  four          0
#7:  8 eight          0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution)

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
v <- paste("case", c("one", "seven", "ten"))
df[!(df$Activity %in% v), ]
```